# When we close the overlay the YouTube video doesn't stop

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors

I am using to open a you tube video in jQuery Model Window.In IE, Safari, Chrome When we close the overlay the YouTube video doesn't stop there but keeps playing in background and then create issues with other video.

My sample Code is

```
<div id="boxes">
    <div class="window" id="dialog" style="top: 11px; left: 323.5px; display: block;">
        <div align="right" class="clsbtn"><a class="close" href="#">Close</a></div>
        <div>
            <object width="580" height="360">
                <param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/eiz2vkSwSeQ&hl=en_US&fs=1&border=1"></param>
                <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param>
                <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param>
                <embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/eiz2vkSwSeQ&hl=en_US&fs=1&border=1" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="580" height="360"></embed>
            </object>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="window" id="dialog" style="top: 11px; left: 323.5px; display: block;"></div>

</div>

<script>
    $('.window .close').click(function (e) {
    //Cancel the link behavior
        e.preventDefault();

        $('#mask').hide();
        $('#mask').css("opacity",0);    
        $('.window').hide();
    });     

    $('#mask').click(function () {
        $('#mask').css("opacity",0);    
        $(this).hide();
        $('.window').hide();
    });     
</script>
```

When I click the thumbnail image the overlay will open and the respective video will play automatically. But I don't know how to stop the the video when we close the overlay.

Comment: O/T Is it intentional that you've got two `div#dialog`?

Comment: Keep the `object` into a js variable. Then when you open modal, add it using `html()` and when someone close the modal, you `remove()`. That's what I did in a website that had a video in a modal. Better than trying to use YT `stopVideo()` which who knows when Google might change that.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.window').find('embed').stopVideo();
```

Or you can link to it directly:

```
$('#myPlayer').stopVideo();
```

Comment: Both methods are failing in IE

Answer (score 0):

Keep the `object` into a js variable.

Then when you open modal, add it using `html(nameOfObjectVar)` and when someone close the modal, you `remove()` it.

That's what I did in a website that had a video in a modal.
Better than trying to use YT `stopVideo()` which who knows when Google might change that.